# Erratic behaviour of MapView's onRegionChange callback

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, react-native-maps

hope you are ok.

Now right to the point, I'm having an issue with MapView Component from   `react-native-maps` through  `expo` and `redux`

**onRegionChange/onRegionChangeComplete** props are behaving laggy and erratic and I cant find out why.

> I've recorded 3 pretty short videos that I hope you watch, **you will
>   understand all of them.**

Here you can see this behavior: https://youtu.be/HvKiC838ZiQ

How do I get here? Follow-on.

First off, I wanted to create a component which allows me to achieve 3 things:

1. Get the location from a device and set it to the component state to fit the region
2. Add a custom-image-marker when **onLongPress**
3. Draw a polygon around the marker to delimit an area for that marker when **onPress**

To achieve this I decided to start for the point 2 & 3 and once complete, ask for location.

So I wrote this:

*This is the redux component state summarized:*

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 initialRegion: {
  latitude: 3.4562823396110987,
  longitude: -76.53087161634343,
  longitudeDelta: 0.020077778360303,
  latitudeDelta: 0.02730640974786524,
 },
 region: {
  latitude: null,
  longitude: null,
  longitudeDelta: null,
  latitudeDelta: null
  },
```

}

*This is the mapComponent I've wrote:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Platform, Constants } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { MapView, Location, Permissions } from 'expo';
import { setCurrentLocation, handlerRegion } from '../actions';

class Map extends Component {
  renderMarker = () => {
    if (this.props.direccion) {
      return (
        <MapView.Marker
          draggable
          coordinate={this.props.direccion}
        >
        <Image
          source={require('../images/LocationIcon.png')}
          style={{ width: 37, height: 56 }}
        />
        </MapView.Marker>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { mapStyle, buttonContainerStyle, trashButtonStyle } = styles;
    const TrashButton = (props) => {
      if (this.props.polygon.length > 0) {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.trash}>
            <View style={trashButtonStyle}>
                <Ionicons name="ios-trash" size={35} color="#eb4050" />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
      return null;
    };
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <MapView
          style={mapStyle}
          initialRegion={this.props.initialRegion}
          onPress={this.props.onPress}
          onLongPress={this.props.onLongPress}
        >
            <MapView.Polygon
              coordinates={this.props.polygon}
              fillColor="rgba(235, 64, 80, 0.5)"
              strokeColor="rgba(235, 64, 80, 1)"
              holes={this.props.holes}
              geodesic
              lineDashPhase={6}
              strokeWidth={2}
            />
            {this.renderMarker()}
        </MapView>
        <View style={buttonContainerStyle}>
          <TrashButton trash={this.props.trashButton} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
    //Extracted for conciseness
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    polygon: state.perfil.polygon,
    region: state.perfil.region,
    direccion: state.perfil.direccion,
    initialRegion: state.perfil.initialRegion
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setCurrentLocation, handlerRegion })(Map);
```

*And this is the parentComponent which has the methods to set marker, polygon, and more:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { MapView } from 'expo';
import { Header } from '../common';
import {
  setRestaurantLocation,
  setPolygonPoint,
  setHoles,
  eraseDeliveryArea,
  saveRestaurantAddress,
  setCurrentLocation,
  handlerRegion
} from '../actions';
import Maps from './Maps';

class DireccionRestaurant extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
  }

  saveRestaurantAddressHandler = () => {
    const { direccion, polygon, user } = this.props;
    this.props.saveRestaurantAddress(direccion, polygon, user);
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
  }

  setRestaurantLocationHandler = (latLng) => {
    if (!this.props.direccion) {
      this.props.setRestaurantLocation(latLng);
    }
  }

  setPolygonPointHandler = (latLng) => {
    if (this.props.direccion) {
      this.props.setPolygonPoint(latLng);
    }
  }

  setHolesHandler = (latLng) => {
    console.log('this is the obj: ', latLng);
    this.props.setHoles(latLng);
  }

  eraseDeliveryAreaHandler = () => {
    this.props.eraseDeliveryArea();
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Header title="Direccion" type="back" button="Guardar" onPress={() => this.saveRestaurantAddressHandler()} backLink={() => navigation.goBack()} />
        <Maps
          onPress={(e => this.setPolygonPointHandler(e.nativeEvent.coordinate))}
          onLongPress={(e => this.setRestaurantLocationHandler(e.nativeEvent.coordinate))}
          trashButton={() => this.eraseDeliveryAreaHandler()}
        />
      </View
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    polygon: state.perfil.polygon,
    holes: state.perfil.holes,
    direccion: state.perfil.direccion,
    user: state.auth.user,
    region: state.perfil.region,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setPolygonPoint,
  setHoles,
  setRestaurantLocation,
  eraseDeliveryArea,
  saveRestaurantAddress,
  setCurrentLocation,
  handlerRegion 
})(DireccionRestaurant);
```

With this setup **I achieved point 2 & 3.** 
You can see here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W7f8wpkiYjo

Ok, so now that all seems to work as intended, I smile and go for the 1 objective: Ask for device location so...

I decide to use the `expo` implementation of `react-native-maps` from AirBNB so I added this prop to my Maps.js component:

```
//class Map extends Component {
getLocationAsync = async () => {
   // let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
   //if (status !== 'granted') {
   // this.setState({
   //   errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
   // });
   // }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    const latitude = location.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = location.coords.longitude;

    this.props.setCurrentLocation(latitude, longitude);
    console.log('this is the latitude mounted: ', latitude, '- this the longitude: ', longitude);
  };
//...
```

*And I also wrote the life-cycle method:*

```
//class Map extends Component {
//...
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getLocationAsync();
  }
//...
```

*So, when componentWillMount it asks for the location and set the location as a new state with this flow:*

**Action**

```
export const setCurrentLocation = (latitude, longitude) => {
  const newState = {
    latitude,
    longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 0.026541072889699535,
    longitudeDelta: 0.019344975439523182,
  };
  return {
    type: SET_ACTUAL_LOCATION,
    payload: newState
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
case SET_ACTUAL_LOCATION:
    return { ...state, region: action.payload };
```

*and Updated the Maps Component:*

```
<MapView
 style={mapStyle}
 initialRegion={this.props.initialRegion}
 region={this.props.region}// <--- Added this
 onPress={this.props.onPress}
 onLongPress={this.props.onLongPress}
>
```

Hooray! location is working so, let's add the marker and.... what?... what happened?. Ok, maybe it's just me. Let's try to create the polygon and... what? it happened again!

See this video to see what happened: https://youtu.be/RlKZvBTVXa0

I think:

> Oh! , this seems to be caused by the absence of an onRegionChange
>   method because when I put a new marker or add a new point, the
>   component re-renders with the last region that was stored on the
>   state. Ok, so I will add an onRegionChangeComplete because it fits
>   more to my needs.

*So now I add this to the Maps.js Component:*

```
<MapView
    style={mapStyle}
    initialRegion={this.props.initialRegion}
    region={this.props.region}
    onPress={this.props.onPress}
    onLongPress={this.props.onLongPress}
    onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => this.props.handlerRegion(region)}//<-ADDED THIS
>
```

*And also write the following redux flow:*

**Action:**

```
export const handlerRegion = (region) => {
  return {
    type: HANDLE_CHANGE_REGION,
    payload: region
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
case HANDLE_CHANGE_REGION:
      return { ...state, region: action.payload };
```

Aaaaaand... the results it's whats happening **in the first video**. 
Here is that video -->: https://youtu.be/HvKiC838ZiQ

The component is fully working. Now the last region stored in the state is the same where we are searching so when I add a marker or a polygon's point it remains where it should. **The only problem left is the laggy and weird behavior that you can see...**

I thought it may be caused by redux, so I tried the same with reactComponent's state but it also happened.

I tried with onRegionChange and onRegionChangeComplete but it's almost the same.

I've searched for others with this same problem, but I didn't find any.

I can't figure out why is this happening. **Do you know why?**

Answer (score 1):

Setting `initialRegion` to `MapView` and removing `region = {this.state.region}` solved similar issue for me.